# Numpy Type (In)consistency?

Tags: python, numpy

In Numpy I tried the following. I suspect that this is not a bug. In case it is a feature, I do not understand it. Can somebody explain this? Thanks.

```
>>> np.array([173], dtype = np.uint8) * [360]
array([62280])
>>> np.array([173], dtype = np.uint8) * 360
array([-3256], dtype=int16)
>>>
```

Comment: I am getting `array([62280], dtype=uint16)` in both case. Numpy 1.8.1 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Getting `array([62280], dtype=uint16)`in both cases, numpy 1.8.1 on Windows, Python 2.7.6

Comment: cannot replicate either using `1.9.0`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Same here, but I can't find any docs about OPs first case, which is still a valid question.

Comment: Seems to be a bug. I use NumPy 1.6.2. This is the standard package on Debian 7 (Wheezy). There is still the question Why the result is not int64 or int32.  Thanks for your Answers.

Comment: @simonzack That's simple element-to-element multiplication. Ndarray's `__mul__`, `__rmul__` and `__imul__` support lists as well.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yes, but I was wondering why it became an int instead of remaining to be `np.uint8` type.

Comment: @simonzack Because it is creating a new array, try: `arr = np.array([173], dtype = np.uint8); arr *= [360]`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary But compare that with `np.array([173], dtype = np.uint8) * np.array([173], dtype = np.uint8)`.

Comment: @simonzack I guess Numpy checks many things. On **assignment** convert  higher types to lower types if possible. If types are same then maintain the type, and if types are different then convert to the higher type.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks, but any doc references?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63099/discussion-between-ashwini-chaudhary-and-simonzack).

Answer (score 1):

The difference between these outputs is probably is caused by a bug in your numpy version.

The code

```
np.array([173], dtype = np.uint8) * [360]
```

is shorthand for:

```
np.array([173], dtype = np.uint8) * np.array([360])
# output array([62280])
```

And thus [360] is transformed to a numpy array with dtype=int. Multiplication takes the highest precision and thus it returns an array with int precision.